# Equivalent of the Office.Application.CompareDocuments in Office.js

Tags: ms-word, add-in, office-js

I do not see any office.js api exposed to compare the documents. Similar api in native office add-in is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195665.aspx

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Compare is basically not available because the new JavaScript API is supposed to function with all available Office clients (Office Online, mobile apps, desktop) and compare is not available on all platforms. Your way out is to send the documents to your backend and run the comparison there on your own - or you'll have to use the classic COM object model

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "compare".  If you're trying to compare in the sense of "is the SHA1 of these documents identical", then you could use the `getFileAsync` API on both documents (assuming there's an add-in in both) and/or the Files REST API (if your file is stored in the cloud).

If by "compare" you mean a more fine-grained comparison, you could compare *many* of the properties by going sheet-by-sheet and comparing the values/formulas/numberFormat/etc. properties on the used range of each sheet.

If you need something in-between (and I'd be curious what it is), please suggest it on UserVoice and post a link here for reference.  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: I'm looking for a comparison between two word documents on Mac office 2016 add-in. I will be fetching base64 byte arrays from the backend server, and need to compare the contents of both, and give merging capability. COM object model offers this functionality off the shelf through Application.CompareDocuments method.

Comment: I tried writing VBA template script (.dotm) that uses Application.CompareDocuments method. It works fine on Windows office. On Mac, it throws error: "Compile error: Method or data not found"  for the line Application.CompareDocuments. Also tried using Applescript. It gives me error "error "Microsoft Word got an error: active document doesn’t understand the “compare” message." number -1708 from active document"     Is it supported on Mac office?

Comment: Re. Mac Office, you may want to start a separate StackOverflow question specifically catered to the VBA audience; though o suspect that the answer you'll get is that while many things in VBA so work across both platforms, there can be subtle differences and occasional omissions on the Mac.  That is part of the value-proposition of our new Office Add-ins model: that, for the APIs we add, they are designed to be cross-platform.